# How to show that$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sin(x)}{x}dx$ exists

Tags: real-analysis

How does one show that  $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \mathrm{d}x$ exists (i.e. does not equal $\infty$), with the most elementary methods possible?

Comment: As far as I know, no basic calculus methods will work on this. You can show that this integral is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ using techniques from complex analysis.

Comment: If you are interested in convergence only apply Dirchlet's integral test.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Clearly:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$$
exists. According to integration by parts:
$$\int^t_1\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\int^t_1-\frac{(\cos(x))'}{x}dx=-\bigg[\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\bigg]^t_1+\int_1^t-\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}=$$
$$=\cos(1)-\frac{\cos(t)}{t}-\int^t_1\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}$$
Hence:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty}\int^t_1\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty}(\cos(1)-\frac{\cos(t)}{t}-\int^t_1\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2})=\cos(1)-\int^{+\infty}_1\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}dx$$
Integral:
$$\int^{+\infty}_1\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}dx$$
is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I=\int_{0}^{\infty}$$\frac{sinx}{x} dx$$=$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-sx}$$\frac{sinx}{x}dx$; ($s=0$)=$L($$\frac{sinx}{x})$=$\int_{s}^{\infty}$$\frac{ds}{1+s^2}$=$cot^{-1}(s)$=$π/2$ at $s=0$.

- *Note:* $L$ stands for Laplace transform defined as $L(f(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}$$e^{-st}f(t)dt$ with $Re(s)>0$.

Comment: your solution contains false statements.

Comment: Which one?...Kindly tell.